# jQuery .fadeIn() not working as expected

Tags: jquery

I have the code below for showing a submenu. I want the submenu to fade in on mouse-over, but it doesn't fade in - it just immediately shows the submenu:

```
jQuery("ul li").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        jQuery(this).find('ul').css('right','0px').css('top','24px');
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul').css('right','-1000px');
});
```

thanks

Comment: why do you give the mouseover a css right and top?

Comment: btw you fade in a li element not your submenu // the ul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the problem, nothing's fading because you're trying to fade the `<li>` you're on, not the `<ul>` beneath it, and it's already visible.  Then, you're moving it in the fade callback, when means it moves on screen *after* the fade completes (and that fade isn't happening anyway).

For the fixes:  A few things here, first you'll probably want [`mouseeneter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) here (which don't fire when entering/leaving child elements).  You can shorten it further by using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), but since you're just positioning and hiding/showing, just do a hide/show, no reason to re-position.  Also make sure you're fading the `<ul>` beneath where you are, not the `<li>` you're on.  Here's the overall look:

```
jQuery("ul li ul").hide().css({ right: 0, top: 24 });
jQuery("ul li").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('ul').fadeIn(1000); //possibly .children('ul') instead
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find('ul').hide();
});
```

This uses the object overrload of [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to shorten it a bit.  But, you could just have this in CSS to start with:

```
ul li ul { right: 0; top: 24; display: none; }
```

Then you could just remove that first line: `jQuery("ul li ul").hide().css({right:0,top:24});`